# Pyspark: join and union in for loop

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a really simple logic that I would like to understand how I can make it work in pyspark.

```
for data in df1:
    spark_data_row = spark.createDataFrame(data=[data])
    spark_data_row = spark_data_row.join(df2)
    df2= df2.union(spark_data_row)
```

Basically, I want to join each row of df_1 to df_2 and then append it to df2 which is initially empty. The resulting df2 is the dataframe of interest for me.

However, spark runs infinitely on even a small dataframe df1 with 100 rows. I am no sure why this is happening. Can someone suggest another way of doing this?

Side note: If I comment out either the join or the union statement in this loop, it works in seconds!

Comment: In general you don't want to iterate over a spark dataframe. Could you explain what you need to do with some input data and expected output? Currently it is hard to understand what you'd like to achieve with this code.

Comment: You can perform your JOIN directly on the dataframe df1. There should be now reason to create a new dataframe for every row.

Comment: @restlessmodem this is not the actual code, I am calling a function there instead of just a join which also does a join in addition to other stuff.

Comment: @ScootCork yes, I understand that iteration is not ideal with spark but this use case is very specific. I understand I might have to change the implementation entirely if this does not work out, but was curios so as to why it does not?